# Plane equation expressed in new orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\pi:x+y+z=0$ describe a plane in the standardbasis. $\pi$ expressed in the new basis $b_1,b_2,b_3$ is $\sqrt{2}\hat{x}+\hat{y}=0$. What is the new basis?

I have read a chapter on change of basis but I honestly have no idea what to do here. Maybe a solution and a link to a text that treats these kind of question would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be the standard basis and $B’$ be the new basis.

I would now use the notation $[\mathbf{v}]_{B}$ to represent the vector $\mathbf{v}$ expressed in the basis $B$.

We note from the two plane equations that the normal vector of the plane in the bases $B$ and $B’$ are $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}_B$ and  $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2} \\ {1} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}_{B'}$ respectively.

These two normal vectors are actually the same vector in the two different bases and can be connected by:

$$
\sqrt{2}[b_1]_B+1[b_2]_B+0[b_3]_B=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}_B
$$

Let $[b_1]_B = \begin{bmatrix}a \\ d \\ g \end{bmatrix}_B$, $[b_2]_B = \begin{bmatrix}b \\ e \\ h \end{bmatrix}_B$ and $[b_3]_B = \begin{bmatrix}c \\ f \\ i \end{bmatrix}_B$. Then we can write down:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}a & b &c \\ d &e &f \\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2} \\ {1} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}_{B'}
=
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}_B
$$

$$
\sqrt{2}\begin{bmatrix}a  \\ d  \\ g \end{bmatrix}+1\begin{bmatrix}b  \\ e  \\ h \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Let $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ d \\ g \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}{1 \over \sqrt{2}}  \\ 0 \\ {1 \over \sqrt{2}} \end{bmatrix}$, then $\begin{bmatrix}b \\ e \\ h \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}0  \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}c \\ f \\ i \end{bmatrix}
=b_1\times b_2
=\begin{bmatrix}{-1 \over \sqrt{2}}  \\ 0 \\ {1 \over \sqrt{2}} \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: So if $B'=\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ and $B=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ then $([b_1]_B \textit{  } [b_2]_B\textit{  } [b_3]_B)[x]_{B'}=[x]_B=x$.

Comment: @perpersson Yes

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the given plane in the standard basis is $n^T r = 0$, where

$r = [x,y,z]^T $ and $n = [1, 1, 1]$.  If we now change the basis to $R = [b_1, b_2, b_3] $, then in this basis the new coordinates are

$ \hat{r} = [\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}]^T = R^T r$

And the equation in the new basis of the same plane will be

$n^T R R^T r = 0 $ i.e. $ n^T R \hat{r} = 0 $ i.e. $\hat{n}^T \hat{r} = 0$

where $\hat{n} = [\sqrt{2}, 1, 0]^T $

Hence,

$\hat{n} = R^T n $

So you're basically asking what rotation matrix $R^T$ will rotate $n$ into $\hat{n} $.  And the answer is that there is an infinite number of these rotation matrices.

The simplest rotation matrix to build is a $180^\circ$ rotation, about the axis given by $( n + \hat{n} ) $

$ n + \hat{n} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 + \sqrt{2} \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

The normalized axis is

$ \hat{a} = \dfrac{n + \hat{n}}{\| n + \hat{n} \|} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{8 + 2 \sqrt{2} }} \begin{bmatrix} 1 + \sqrt{2} \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Since the rotation is by $180^\circ$ then (by the Rodrigues rotation matrix formula)

$ R^T = {\hat{a} \hat{a}}^T + (I - {\hat{a} \hat{a}}^T) \cos 180^\circ = 2 {\hat{a} \hat{a}}^T - I $

and this is equal to

$ R^T = \dfrac{1}{4 +  \sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} -1 +  \sqrt{2} && 2 + 2 \sqrt{2} && 1 +  \sqrt{2} \\ 2 + 2 \sqrt{2} && - \sqrt{2} && 2 \\ 1 +  \sqrt{2} && 2 && -3 -  \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} $

One can check that $R^T n =\hat{n} $

Therefore, the orthonormal basis vectors are the columns of $R$

$b_1 = \dfrac{1}{4 + \sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} -1 + \sqrt{2} \\ 2 + 2 \sqrt{2} \\ 1 + \sqrt{2}  \end{bmatrix}, \hspace{25pt} b_2 = \dfrac{1}{4+\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 2 + 2 \sqrt{2} \\ - \sqrt{2} \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}, \hspace{25pt} b_3 = \dfrac{1}{4 + \sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 + \sqrt{2} \\ 2 \\ - 3 - \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} $

**EDIT**:

As a generalization, and starting from

$ \hat{n} = R^T n $

Note that the columns of $R=[b_1, b_2,b_3]$ are unit vectors, that satisfy

$ \sqrt{2} = b_1 \cdot [1, 1, 1]^T $

$ 1 = b_2 \cdot [1, 1, 1]^T $

$ 0 = b_3 \cdot [ 1, 1, 1]^T $

Starting with $b_3$, we find that it can expressed as

$ b_3 = \cos(t) [1, -1, 0]^T/\sqrt{2} + \sin(t) [1, 1, -2]/\sqrt{6} $

Now, for $b_2$ we get

$b_2 = [1, 1, 1]^T/3 + \sqrt{2/3}\cos(s) [1, -1, 0]^T/\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2/3} \sin(s) [1, 1, -2]/\sqrt{6} $

and finally,

$ b_1 = \sqrt{2} [1, 1, 1]^T / 3 + \sqrt{1/3} \cos(r)[1, -1, 0]^T /\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{1/3} \sin(r) [1, 1, -2]/\sqrt{6} $

Applying orthgonality to these vectors, we get

$ (b_3, b_2): \cos(t) \cos(s) + \sin(t) \sin(s) = 0 $

$ (b_3, b_1): \cos(t) \cos(r) + \sin(t) \sin(r) = 0 $

$ (b_2, b_1): \cos(s) \cos(r) + \sin(s) \sin(r) = -1 $

These conditions become,

$ \cos(t - s) = 0 $

$ \cos(t - r) = 0 $

$ \cos(s - r) = -1 $

We can choose $t$ and solve for $r$ and $s$ from the above three equations.

For example, choose $t = 0$, then take $r = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $ s = - \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

Then it follows that

$ b_1 =  \sqrt{2} [1, 1, 1]^T / 3 + \sqrt{1/3} [1, 1, -2]/\sqrt{6} $

Which simplifies to

$ b_1 = [1, 1, 0] / \sqrt{2}  $

And

$b_2 = [1, 1, 1]^T/3 - \sqrt{2/3} [1, 1, -2]/\sqrt{6} $

$ b_2 = [0, 0, 1]^T $

And

$b_3 = [1, -1, 0]^T/\sqrt{2} $

So that

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} && 0 && \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} && 0 && - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
0 && 1 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

is the rotation matrix whose columns are the new basis vectors.